# Categorizing and grouping data

Tags: r

I am having difficulty finding the right code for this question: Fields of expertise are a mess - how can I cluster them into summarized fields:

- Business = Finance, HR, Sales, Marketing, Business development
- Engineering = Robotics, Engineering, IT support, DevOps, Data Science

The expected result is:

```r
col1(Inputs)                                         col2(Result)
Finance, HR, Robotics, Engineering, Sales            Business, Engineering
DevOps, Data Science, Marketing, IT Support          Business, Engineering
UI/UX, HR, Graphic Design                            Other, Business
Business development                                 Business
```

In other words, the result should not be like this:

```
col1(Inputs)                                   col2(Result)
Finance, HR, Robotics, Engineering, Sales      Biz, Biz, Engineer, Engineer, Biz
DevOps, Data Science, Marketing, IT support    Engineer, Engineer, Biz, Engineer
UI/UX, HR, Graphic Design                      Other, Biz, Other
```

Thank you very much for the answer. I'm thinking about having 2 FOR loops, but then I am stuck in defining the variables i,j.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jessie! Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: My apologies. I'm quite new to R, and I really do not know how to provide codes with that problem. Thus, I thought that explaining the question and expected results in Excel would help people understand it.

Comment: Images of data presumes that we will take the time to transcribe or scrape your stuff. It might be necessary at times, but you are much less likely to get much attention (other than downvotes) relying on that. Since you have excel there, consider saving the data as CSV, then [edit] your question and insert the raw contents of each CSV file as separate [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Is there an API, known list, or something else that provides hints on the human-readable categories? You aren't going to find a simple program that can do this without some training and/or string patterns (perhaps regex).

Comment: Sorry, but there's no hint. I did try using apply, sapply but these functions did not work quite well.

Comment: To start this process, I would think there would need to be a dictionary or translation from (say) "Finance" or "HR" to "Business", and "Robotics" or "Engineering" to "Engineering". If you don't have that translation layer, I don't know of any function that will intuit what you think you need here.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this! I have edited the post (again). Typically, I'm dealing with 2 fields (UI/UX, Design,... belong to "Other" group):                                                                                                      
 1. Business = Finance, HR, Sales, Marketing, Business development
 2.Engineering = Robotics, Engineering, IT support, DevOps, Data Science

Comment: Jessie, you're holding out. If you have two fields with their candidate professions, then you need to provide that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journey.

Data,

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "|", text = "
Inputs                                      | Result
Finance, HR, Robotics, Engineering, Sales   | Business, Engineering
DevOps, Data Science, Marketing, IT Support | Business, Engineering
UI/UX, HR, Graphic Design                   | Other, Business
Business development                        | Business")
dat[] <- lapply(dat, trimws)
dat
#                                        Inputs                Result
# 1   Finance, HR, Robotics, Engineering, Sales Business, Engineering
# 2 DevOps, Data Science, Marketing, IT Support Business, Engineering
# 3                   UI/UX, HR, Graphic Design       Other, Business
# 4                        Business development              Business
```

BTW: I would generally recommend against the structure of comma-separated values within a frame column: any time you want to look at individual values, you need to parse/separate the fields, do something, and then recombine them. While this is not extremely difficult, it is inefficient, and there can always be problems.

Now, the translation from the left to the right:

```r
fields <- list(
  Business = c("Finance", "HR", "Sales", "Marketing", "Business development"),
  Engineering = c("Robotics", "Engineering", "IT Support", "DevOps", "Data Science")
)
inv_fields <- setNames(rep(names(fields), lengths(fields)), unlist(fields))
inv_fields
#              Finance                   HR                Sales            Marketing Business development 
#           "Business"           "Business"           "Business"           "Business"           "Business" 
#             Robotics          Engineering           IT support               DevOps         Data Science 
#        "Engineering"        "Engineering"        "Engineering"        "Engineering"        "Engineering"
```

I first defined `fields` in *that* way because I think it's easier to see and maintain. However, for the trick further down (indexing on it), I need the *name* of each element to be the left (career) and the *value* to be the right (field). We don't use `fields` itself.

First attempt, I'll split the strings and then run the indexing:

```r
lapply(strsplit(dat$Inputs, ","), function(z) inv_fields[trimws(z)])
# [[1]]
#       Finance            HR      Robotics   Engineering         Sales 
#    "Business"    "Business" "Engineering" "Engineering"    "Business" 
# [[2]]
#        DevOps  Data Science     Marketing          <NA> 
# "Engineering" "Engineering"    "Business"            NA 
# [[3]]
#       <NA>         HR       <NA> 
#         NA "Business"         NA 
# [[4]]
# Business development 
#           "Business"
```

Unfortunately, we lose `IT Support`, because your comment had it spelled as `IT support` (lower-case "s"). While this one thing is an easy fix, I feel it's possible (likely, even) that there will be case differences that you want to ignore. So we'll deal with the lower-case version of everything (during the lookup):

```r
# redefine, using lower-case
inv_fields_lc <- setNames(rep(names(fields), lengths(fields)), tolower(unlist(fields)))
lapply(strsplit(dat$Inputs, ","), function(z) inv_fields_lc[tolower(trimws(z))])
# [[1]]
#       finance            hr      robotics   engineering         sales 
#    "Business"    "Business" "Engineering" "Engineering"    "Business" 
# [[2]]
#        devops  data science     marketing    it support 
# "Engineering" "Engineering"    "Business" "Engineering" 
# [[3]]
#       <NA>         hr       <NA> 
#         NA "Business"         NA 
# [[4]]
# business development 
#           "Business"
```

Now we need to address the missing values and replace them with `"Other"`, and reduce duplicate entries:

```r
lapply(strsplit(dat$Inputs, ","), function(z) {
  out <- inv_fields_lc[tolower(trimws(z))]
  out[is.na(out)] <- "Other"
  unique(out)
})
# [[1]]
# [1] "Business"    "Engineering"
# [[2]]
# [1] "Engineering" "Business"   
# [[3]]
# [1] "Other"    "Business"
# [[4]]
# [1] "Business"
```

We can then combine (`paste`) these and add them as a column to the original frame. (Again, I don't like comma-separated strings like this in frames, it might be more useful to use *list-columns*, but it depends heavily on the rest of your processing.)

```r
dat$Result2 <- sapply(strsplit(dat$Inputs, ","), function(z) {
  out <- inv_fields_lc[tolower(trimws(z))]
  out[is.na(out)] <- "Other"
  paste(sort(unique(out)), collapse = ", ")
})
dat
#                                        Inputs                Result               Result2
# 1   Finance, HR, Robotics, Engineering, Sales Business, Engineering Business, Engineering
# 2 DevOps, Data Science, Marketing, IT Support Business, Engineering Business, Engineering
# 3                   UI/UX, HR, Graphic Design       Other, Business       Business, Other
# 4                        Business development              Business              Business
```

(I added a `sort` too, not sure if that's desired.)